# How can I link libc statically with just ld?

Tags: linux, assembly, ld, static-linking

I want to link libc statically with just ld. I got it right (dynamically) with ld -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 prog.o -lc. I thought i have to find the right objectcode for the libc functions and tried to link against /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a. It didn't work. What do I wrong here?

Comment: Don't do that. If you insist use `gcc -static -v prog.o` and then `gcc` will print the correct invocation of `ld` (possibly via `collect2`) that you can use.

Comment: Statically linking in the libc is not easy because as opposed to a dynamically linked libc, you need to manually initialise the library.